# Get date of last push on github pull request

Tags: github, github-api

From the GitHub API you can get a list of commits on a PR, with their commit dates. Like this:
https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-commits-on-a-pull-request

These dates seem to be commit datetimes to me. I was wondering if it is possible to obtain the push datetimes.

I want to recreate the order of comments and commits as it is presented on a GitHub PR webpage.

Comment: This information exists on the client who did the push.  `git log -1` produces information about the very last commitid, author, date and commit message.  Filter it down to just the date with `git log -1 --format=%cd` which produces: `Fri Jul 13 06:32:54 2018 -0400`.  It sounds like you're asking for information about events on the client, not information about events on the repository server, so you're technically asking for information that's isn't yours.  Get root on their box bro then you can know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only two places you can get the timestamps for when a push happened are:

1) The Events API -- https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/. See the PushEvent: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent. But that API will return only the last 300 events from the past 90 days

2) webhooks -- http://developer.github.com/webhooks/. See the pull_request event which tells you when the head branch is updated through a push (`synchronize`). But you need to have admin permissions for a repository to be able to create webhooks.